# Find daily-max combined with exact date-time

Tags: matlab, date

I try to solve my problem and could not find a good solution yet-by using Matlab! 
I have a matrix with date (hourly resolution) and also measured values. I need to have the max-value of the day but also the exact date ('dd.mm.yyyy HH:MM').

parameters: date and 'temp length(1:4129)

```
date:734624.041666667   201105010100.000    2011    5   1   1   0   0
temp:-1.91450000000000
     -0.0627500000000000
      ...
```

1) I have tried peakdet() which does not consider another vector, only the distance from the peak, so it did not give me the required result.

```
[pks,locs] = findpeaks(temp,'npeaks',173); % lengths: 173 (days) but only finds absolute peaks
```

2) I have already used diff() to get the row numbers of the day-breaks, then I could calculate the max value, however the date is still missing.

How do I get the max value of one day - how to do p.ex. do a loop to get a matrix of the max value and the date!?

Comment: datestr and datenum could be useful ;)

Comment: Can you make it more clear how your data is stored? Is it one vector for date and one vector for your measurement? In what format do you have your time data? serial date number? strings? Is there data missing or can we assume that each consecutive 24 time and measurement values belong to the same day? If so, a combination of reshape() and max() might do the job for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I have the date-time in several formats - also in datenum! it is one vector for the date which has also one measurement-value. there is no data missing (no NaN values), but I dont assume a regular course of the data. ie. I want the max of the data depending on the date, so reshaphe() and max() are not enough I guess.